# Coinbase Pro /profiles/transfer

Tags: api, oauth, transfer, coinbase-api

I need to be able to transfer crypto from one use to another user of Coinbase automatically via a cron job.

I have configured an API key in Coinbase Pro which includes transfer capabilities.  Unfortunately when the PHP CURL call to the API is executed I receive the following error:

> "{"message":"This API key does not have permission to transfer from
> this profile."}"

I have double checked then key's permission and it does have transfer turned on, I have even created a second key with the exact same permission and it results in the same issue.

Could some kind soul direct me in the correct direction to get past this issue.  I have been struggling with the Coinbase API and the Coinbase Pro API for over a week now and this is the last issue I have not been able to resolve.

FYI, The source Coinbase account does have transfer out capability and the target Coinbase account does have transfer in capability.  I confirmed this earlier by using the Coinbase app to transfer crypto between the two accounts successfully, albeit using not the user account IDs but wallet IDs as that is what the Coinbase app provides.  Perhaps that is a clue?

I believe my PHP curl call to the Coinbase Pro API is correct but I am including it here for completeness.

```
    // Get timestamp
    $API_VERSION = '2021-02-26';
    $timestamp = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/time"), true)["data"]["epoch"];
    
    // Set request
    $req = "/profiles/transfer";
    
    // Set URL
    $url = "https://api.pro.coinbase.com" . $req;
    
    // Set API key, secret , and passphrase
    $key="abcdefghijklmnop";
    $secret="really_long_secret_string_goes_here_and_was_confirmed_correct";
    $passphrase="thisisapassphrase";
    
    // Set the params for the POST call
    
    $params = [
      "type" => "send",
      "from" => "72e49875-fab4-5049-9c68-abcdefghijklmno" , 
      "to" => "e867c62e-71d2-58bc-95cd-abcdefghijklmno",
      "amount" => "0.000001",
      "currency" => "BCH"
              ];
    
    // Make PHP Curl Call
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'CoinbaseProAPI');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , json_encode($params) );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array ( "Content-Type: application/json"
                                                   , "CB-VERSION:" . $API_VERSION
                                                   , "CB-ACCESS-SIGN:" 
                       . signaturePro( $req , $params , $timestamp , "POST", $secret )                                                                                                
                                                   , "CB-ACCESS-KEY:" . $key
                                                   , "CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE:" . $passphrase
                                                   , "CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP:" . $timestamp                                                                     
                                                   )
                  );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $response_obj=json_encode($response);
    
    echo $response_obj;

// Taken straight from Coinbase Pro API documentation (As best I remember)    
function signaturePro($request_path='', $body='', $timestamp=false, $method='GET', $secret ) {                                                                                                                    
        $body = is_array($body) ? json_encode($body) : $body;
        $timestamp = $timestamp ? $timestamp : time();

        $what = $timestamp.$method.$request_path.$body;

        return base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $what, base64_decode($secret), true));
    }
```

Any and all insights are welcome.  I will happily abandon the Coinbase Pro API if this desired functionality can be achieved in the Coinbase API or any other Coinbase provided API.  I do prefer to use Curl rather than another library which I would need to learn.

Solution:

Turns out in my Coinbase Security settings I had 2FA turned on, this setting must be in the off position for the API to work.

[image]